# Conversion from string "F:\Steam\steamapps\common\FSX" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

I  am making an installer for a flight sim thing but when I use them following code I get this message: Conversion from string "F:\Steam\steamapps\common\FSX" to type 'Double' is not valid

Here is the code:

```
    Private Sub FsX1Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FsX1Button2.Click

    Try
        If TextBox1.Text = Not "" Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(TextBox1.Text & "\SimObjects\Misc\ControlTower\texture\ControlTower_Instruments_lm.dds")
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(TextBox1.Text & "\SimObjects\Misc\ControlTower\texture\ControlTower_Instruments.dds")
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(TextBox1.Text & "\SimObjects\Misc\ControlTower\texture\ControlTower_Countertops2_lm.dds")
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(TextBox1.Text & "\SimObjects\Misc\ControlTower\texture\ControlTower_Countertops2.dds")
            Dim bravo() As Byte = My.Resources.ControlTower_Countertops2

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(TextBox1.Text & "\SimObjects\Misc\ControlTower\texture\ControlTower_Countertops2.dds", bravo)

            Dim charlie() As Byte = My.Resources.ControlTower_Countertops_lm

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(TextBox1.Text & "\SimObjects\Misc\ControlTower\texture\ControlTower_Countertops2_lm.dds", charlie)

            Dim delta() As Byte = My.Resources.ControlTower_Instruments

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(TextBox1.Text & "\SimObjects\Misc\ControlTower\texture\ControlTower_Instruments.dds", delta)

            Dim foxtrot() As Byte = My.Resources.ControlTower_Instruments_lm

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(TextBox1.Text & "\SimObjects\Misc\ControlTower\texture\ControlTower_Instruments_lm.dds", foxtrot)
            Me.Hide()
            MsgBox("Installed successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "")
            End
        Else
            MsgBox("Select path", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error exporting the files (" + ex.Message + ")", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub FsX1Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FsX1Button1.Click
    FolderSelect.ShowDialog()
    TextBox1.Text = FolderSelect.SelectedPath
End Sub
```

So you press the button and select the folder and it sets TextBox1 to the file path. Then it adds the files.

However, When i use the following code:

```
        Try
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("C:\ProjectRazerFiles")
        Dim b() As Byte = My.Resources.ControlTower_Countertops2

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\ProjectRazerFiles\ControlTower_Countertops2.dds", b)

        Dim c() As Byte = My.Resources.ControlTower_Countertops_lm

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\ProjectRazerFiles\ControlTower_Countertops2_lm.dds", c)

        Dim d() As Byte = My.Resources.ControlTower_Instruments

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\ProjectRazerFiles\ControlTower_Instruments.dds", d)

        Dim f() As Byte = My.Resources.ControlTower_Instruments_lm

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\ProjectRazerFiles\ControlTower_Instruments_lm.dds", f)
        MsgBox("Exported successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error exporting the files (" + ex.Message + ")", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End Try
```

It works?

Can you help me with the top one please?
Any help would be gratefully appreciated

Comment: On what line of code are you getting the error? Would you edit your question to indicate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you obviously have option strict set to off, turn it on and fix all of the errors you get (including this one).  If you have more than a few hundred, you should turn it on at the project level and off at the file level.

The `Not ""` is obviously turning the empty string into a double (using the equivalent of Val("")) and then performing a bitwise Not on it and then trying to compare the result to TextBox1.Text by converting it's value to a double, which it fails to do and thus your exception.

Option Strict Off allows these types of comparisions, and in some cases it even works out to roughly what you meant to happen. In other cases, as this example shows, it just causes a compile time error to become a runtime error.  That is seldom an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is presumably here:

```
If TextBox1.Text = Not "" Then
```

That code doesn't make sense.  It's trying to negate an empty `String` and compare the result to another `String`.  If you're trying to test that the `TextBox` is not empty then that would be like this:

```
If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
```